# Accessing obj as property vs method param (style preferences)

Tags: ios, objective-c

When it comes to accessing objects from different methods in the **same** class, from what I understand, these are two ways to do it. Given that I **DO** want to hold a property pointer to this object, which is the better way to go about this? I've been thinking about this for a while, and wondered if there is a preference consensus.

**#1:**

```
NSArray *array = ... // Get array from somewhere
self.myArray = array;

[self doSomethingToMyArray];
```

This method takes no parameter and accesses the array via its own property via self

```
- (void)doSomethingToMyArray
{
// Do stuff with/to the array via self.myArray
[self.myArray ...];
}
```

Vs **#2:**

```
NSArray *array = ... // Get array from somewhere
self.myArray = array;

[self doSomething:array];
```

This method takes an array and accesses the array via its own method parameter

```
- (void)doSomething:(NSArray *)array
{
// Do stuff with/to the array via method parameter "array"
[array ...];
}
```

Comment: Option 2 is far more flexible. It will work with any array, not just the property. Do it this way from the start. Otherwise some time down the road you'll find a need to work with a different array and you will end up refactoring the code. Avoid that work later by having your method take a parameter now.

Comment: It will **compile** any array as an argument.  Whether it will **work** with any array really depends on what the method does. Does it use any of the object's other state? (If not, why is this even a method on that class, and not a free function or a category method on `NSArray`?) Does that state need to be in sync with the argument array in some way?  Whether the method should be written to take the array as an argument depends entirely on what the method does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's primarily going to depend on what `doSomethingToMyArray` does and who calls it.

Fairly obvious comments:

- if you want to do that to more than one array, you need to take an argument;
- if what you're doing is actually logically more to do with the array than with your class (e.g. you've implemented randomisation of the order of the array) then it'd be better as a category on `NSArray` rather than being anywhere in that class at all;
- if there's any possibility of subclasses wanting to redefine the manner in which the array is obtained then you'll want to invoke the getter somewhere;
- similar concerns apply if a subclass or an external actor should be able to intercede anywhere else in the process.

Beyond those concerns there are a bunch of us that just prefer this stuff to be functional anyway — noting that you're doing something *to* the array, not *with* the array, in which case you'd tend more towards `self.myArray = [self processedFormOf:array]` (or `self.myArray = [array arrayByDoingSomething];` if the category tip makes sense).

So, ummm, I don't think there's a clear-cut answer.

Comment: "ToMyArray" was kind of just the first thing I thought of, but you're right about To vs With. I was thinking in terms of a private method thats just meant to refactor out some common code to do one thing (i.e. count # of occurrences of something in the array). So in my original problem, _myArray vs self.myArray, and the two ways mentioned above are pretty much exactly the same thing, so I thought it would boil down to a style preference.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on what you want to do, just by reading it:

```
   doSomething:array
```

I would assume the above method takes ANY array and performs an action, whereas:

```
    doSomethingToMyArray
```

with this method you are describing the intention of doing something to  your instance's array. Inside this method (given that you followed Apple good coding practices and you synthesized your property to _myArray) , you could either go with:

```
    [self.myArray message]
```

or preferably

```
    [_myArray message]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second option is sort of silly. If you're storing a pointer in an instance, then it's so that you can use it later (within that instance) without needing to pass it around whenever you call a method.

This is also dependent on whether you're using ARC or not (use ARC if this is a new project). In a non-ARC project, `self.myArray = foo;` will do a very different thing than `myArray = foo;` (the `self.` syntax calls a property, which in many cases will correctly retain the thing you've assigned). In an ARC project, they'll generally have the same behavior, and there's less room for error.

Personally, in my ARC projects, I do not use the `self.` syntax from within a class, since it's just extra typing for the same effect. This ties in nicely with the new usage of `@property`, where you're no longer required to write a `@synthesize` block, and Objective-C will automatically generate an ivar for you, with the name of your property prefixed by an underscore, i.e. `_myPropertyName`. That makes it very clear visually when you're accessing code from outside the class (crossing the encapsulation boundary), where things will look like `foo.bar = baz;` versus inside the class, where it's just `_bar = baz;`.

Comment: `self.property` doesn't technically the same effect as `_property = ` since subclasses may override the setter and/or getter, and — more vitally — not using the setter means not being KVO compliant.

Comment: Like I mentioned, in general they have the same behavior. If you're using KVO in iOS, you need to be more careful and generally I can't recommend it to new iOS developers. In practice, I don't believe KVO is a very commonly used technique in iOS development.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, clearly, a function call would incur an extra overhead.

- you would have to allocate an object pointer (though minimal) over the stack (extra memory)
- Have to pass it (extra processing)

Property is actually a small function call unless you have made customizations to the getter.  I also assume that compiler may have its own optimizations put in place for such accessors so that you can access them with minimal overhead, though I do not have any source to cite this.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil.](http://hans.gerwitz.com/2004/08/12/premature-optimization-is-the-root-of-all-evil.html)  Who cares whether there's a single message-send's overhead unless the optimizer says it's a hotspot?